# How to set Chromium custom tab default = disable

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Chromium 63 code. When I click a link, it will open Chromium custom tab. I need to open the link in Chromium browser instead of in Chromium custom tab. How to change the Chromium code (not change chrome://flags) for it?

Comment: I found Chrome works the as I needed. when click a link outside the Chrome browser, it will open Chrome browser instead of open Chrome custom tab. How to change the Chromium code to get this action?

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of adding a comment with another question.